# How do i make a complex shape with one object?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I know i could just plop a rectangle onto this building to make the shape correct, but I was wondering if there was a better way to make this building out of one object. I am trying to recreate durr burger restaurant, but am finding that things get messy real fast with the sloped roof that is only on one side and not on the other. Here is my dilemna in a picture. Is there a proper way to make a sloped roof like this without using a cube object to work as the none sloped part of the building? Thx for all advice[image][image]

enter image description here

Comment: This is very basic - try to fiddle with Extrude (E) and Scale (S). For example you can make a main profile of the building, then extrude it up to create the first floor, another extrude to create the roof, scale it down etc. Then you can use Knife (K) or Loop Cut (Ctrl R) and extrude new polygons to create that "cube shape".

Comment: I tried loopcuts, but those didn't let me make the corners on the roof right, so I think the knife tool is working, except, it isn't ideal as it creates faces with more than four points. Oh well though

Comment: How do I make the orange lines? Would that require knife tool? or a loopcut?